# Jmeter: Error in Test Plan: Conversion error

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm new to jmeter (as in just started reading about it last week.)  I've been given some tests written by someone that's left the company but I cannot get the tests to open in jmeter.  According to the .jmx file,

it was written in jmeter 2.9 so I installed 2.9.  I got the standard plugins, but it just isn't loading, please see the error message below and let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks!

2015/03/02 13:35:23 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor

```
---- Debugging information ----
message             : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[2]/hashTree[3]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
line number         : 113
------------------------------- : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
```

---- Debugging information ----
    message             : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
    cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
    cause-message       : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
    class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[2]/hashTree[3]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
    line number         : 113
    -------------------------------
    message             : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor

```
---- Debugging information ----
message             : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[2]/hashTree[3]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
line number         : 113
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:65)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan
```

/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[2]/hashTree[3]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
line number         : 113
version             : 2.9 r1437961

Answer (score 0):

Last Jmeter.plugins require Jmeter 2.11 to work.
I think you have to upgrade Jmeter OR to uninstall Jmeter.plugins.
I would try to upgrade Jmeter to 2.12, usually it makes no harms.